# the definition of normal vector

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I got confused with definitions of a normal vector.

Assume, that $X \in \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and let $Y = 1 - X$. Is this true that 
$(X, Y)$ is multivariate normal?

The problem is that according to the first definition of a multivariate normal vector, any linear combination of the components must be a normal random variable. In the example above we have that $P[X + Y = 1] = 1$. Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Why do you think this is a contradiction?

Comment: because the sum is a constant with probability 1. Can we think of a constant as of a random variable.

Comment: Can you write the co-variance matrix of the (X,Y)? What do you observe?

Comment: as for as I can see, the covariance matrix in this case is singular. This is allowed. We won't have a density function for $(X, Y)$.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Thats why you get that the sum is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction here.

Due to the way the RVs are defined, the joint variable have a singular covariance matrix. This is the reason why the sum is equal to a constant.

In this case, the joint variable does not have a density; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case

Comment: While true, the statement "the joint variable does not have a density" can be misleading.  The joint variable will not have a density over the joint space because its support is of zero measure over that space.  However, if one restricts consideration to the subspace over which the joint variable is supported, it will have a derivable "function" that acts like a density over that subspace, even though measure theory refuses to admit that it actually a density.

Comment: Among other places this arises, it is front and center in characterizing the statistics of rank-deficient Wishart matrices (which even though they lack a "density" a the formal sense, can be quantitatively characterized).